# Snowflake Row Access Policy privileges

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform, snowflake-schema

I am unable to find the list of privilege's that are required -

1.) For a Role to create Row Access Policy
2.) Grant Usage on the Policy to a different Role
3.) Grant Modify on the Policy to a different Role

Need simple step by step example starting from DBADMIN.

Answer (score 3):

Snowflake supports adding and dropping row access policies in a single SQL statement.

For a given resource (i.e. table or view), to `ADD` or `DROP` a row access policy you must have either the `APPLY ROW ACCESS POLICY` privilege on the schema, or the `OWNERSHIP` privilege on the resource and the `APPLY` privilege on the row access policy resource.

The `APPLY` privilege allows `ADD` and `DROP` operations for the Row Access Policies on a table or view, and executing the `DESCRIBE` operation on tables and views.

The `OWNERSHIP` privilege allows full control over the row access policy. This is required to alter most properties of a row access policy. Only a single role can hold this privilege on a specific object at a time.

`USAGE` privilege on the parent database and schema are also required.

[Row Access Policy Privileges](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/security-access-control-privileges.html#row-access-policy-privileges)

Comment: yup, grants are documented, you have the choice of going centralised or decentralised governance or something in between, Snowflake recommends creating a custom POLICY_ADMIN role, the name you decide, it's custom. Let us know if the docs and the above advice are enough